# Div's not responsively behaving as expected

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div's and the center div is not behaving as expected,

I've got HEADER div ---> sub-content div ---> services-section

the sub-content div is not responsively behaving as expected, image here: http://prntscr.com/p2roxk

the other div's are working 100%

```css
.sub-content {
  background: #FF4E00;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 280px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
}

.sub-content h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sub-content p {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!--Sub Content-->
<div class="sub-content">
  <h2>Professional website development</h2>
  <p>**** is a professional website & graphics development company based in South Africa, we can offer modern creative and responsive designs to best suit your needs.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define "not working as expected" What is your expectation?

Comment: You have margin on the h2, and you giv the div margin-top that det his start point

Comment: @Omer There's no margin on the .sub-content h2 but there's a padding-top of 30px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice you are using height as a fixed value. You can chage it by using min-height in place of height.
Example:

```
.sub-content {
  background: #FF4E00;
  min-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 280px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: So how do I add a spacing so its not as close to the buttons? Picture: http://prntscr.com/p2ywi2

Comment: Can you please add the full code or share the url so I can check and let you know.